How to add a custom attribute to the default NextJS span?
I'm using vercel otel for sending opentelemetry traces and monitoring them on Azure application insights. The project is a NextJS 14 project. I have the instrumentation hook enabled so NextJS sends spans by default without me having to create them. I can see the traces on Azure and everything is working fine.
What I want now is to inject custom attributes to the spans sent out for better tracing. I still want to use the default spans NextJS is sending, but before exporting I want to attach those attributes as well.
Here is my instrumentation.ts file.
import type { SpanExporter } from "@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-base";
import { registerOTel } from "@vercel/otel";


export async function register() {
  let traceExporter: SpanExporter | undefined;

  if (process.env.NEXT_RUNTIME === "nodejs") {
    const { AzureMonitorTraceExporter } = await import(
      "@azure/monitor-opentelemetry-exporter"
    );
    traceExporter = new AzureMonitorTraceExporter({
      connectionString: process.env.APP_INSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING,
    });
  }

  registerOTel({
    serviceName: process.env.NODE_ENV,
    traceExporter,
  });
}


Figured it out. Need a span processor to manipulate it before exporting. Vercel otel doesn't mention it in the documentation but we can add a processor to registerOTEL. Here's the modified code.
import type {
  SpanExporter,
  SpanProcessor,
  Span,
  ReadableSpan,
} from "@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-base";

import { registerOTel } from "@vercel/otel";

export async function register() {
  let traceExporter: SpanExporter | undefined;

  if (process.env.NEXT_RUNTIME === "nodejs") {
    const { AzureMonitorTraceExporter } = await import(
      "@azure/monitor-opentelemetry-exporter"
    );
    traceExporter = new AzureMonitorTraceExporter({
      connectionString: process.env.APP_INSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING,
    });
  }

  class SpanEnrichingProcessor implements SpanProcessor {
    forceFlush(): Promise<void> {
      return Promise.resolve();
    }

    shutdown(): Promise<void> {
      return Promise.resolve();
    }

    onStart(_span: Span): void {}

    onEnd(span: ReadableSpan) {
      // Add custom dimensions to the span.
      span.attributes["CustomDimension1"] = "value1";
      span.attributes["CustomDimension2"] = "value2";
    }
  }
  let processor = new SpanEnrichingProcessor();

  registerOTel({
    serviceName: process.env.NODE_ENV,
    traceExporter,
    spanProcessors: [processor],
  });
}

